# Php, MySql query, two COUNT one GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, count

I dont know if is possible with single query.

Here is my table:

```
id  name        body
------------------------------
1   Toyota      SUV
2   Mazda       Sedan
3   Crysler     Wagon
4   Mercedes    Van
5   Merceds     SUV
6   Mazda       SUV

etc...
```

and here is the query:

```
SELECT 
  name,
  COUNT(name) AS make_total,
  COUNT(body) AS body_total 
FROM
  cars 
GROUP BY name;
```

If I group by name "make_total" is correct, if I group by body than "body_total" count is correct, but never the both.

The expected result should produce correct count for each name and body fields.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? This query works as expected, unless you're looking to count `distinct` values, in that case see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT colname)`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) AS make_total,
       COUNT(DISTINCT body) AS body_total
FROM cars
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not produce the expected result. With your example I only get one row and correct counters, but i need to retrieve all the results from name column grouped by name

Comment: What do  you expect to be in the `body_total` column if you group by name? Could you add the expected results to your question so we understand what you want?

Comment: Sorry about that. I just reliased that its not possible to do it with single query. I went different route. Thanks for your time